# Conditional Servo Movement

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, servo

I am currently working on getting a raspberry pi to drive a servo motor according to a set condition.

In the final program I will have a sensor determining the level of water in a glass, when this level reaches the limit I would like to activate the servo. I would then like it to reset back to its original position once the water level has gone back below the threshold.

To do this I have been simulating the threshold with a for loop.

This is the code I currently have:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

servoPIN = 5
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN, GPIO.OUT)
p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50)

def move_servo(p, dc):
    p.start(2.5) 
    try:
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(dc)
        time.sleep(1.2)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        p.stop()

while True:

    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        if i >=5:
            move_servo(p, 20.5) 
        else:
            move_servo(p, 2.5)       

        print(i)


    GPIO.cleanup()
```

This works as I would expect for the first time that it runs, when it is below 5 the servo remains stationary and once the 'threshold' of 5 is hit the servo moves 180*.

The problem I am having however, is once the program has run once and the for loop has reset (i.e. the water level has gone back below the threshold) the servo does not move back or even attempt to maintain its position, it is simply off.

I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction as to how I can make a program that will allow the constant movement back and forth of the servo motor depending on the condition of if the threshold has been met or not.

Comment: I don't think you want to call cleanup inside the while loop. Put it outside by removing the indentation. Don't know if that solves your problem though

Comment: @Dirk Wow thank you, that one indent was all that was causing the issue, it is able to move back and forth now each time. Thank you for pointing it out!!

Comment: @Dirk why not make your comment an answer?  That would allow closure on the question.